# How to Transfer Files from Client to Server Computer by using python script?

Tags: python

- I am writing a python script to copy python(say ABC.py) files from one directory to another 
  directory with the same folder name(say ABC) as script name excluding .py.
- In the local system it works fine and copying the files from one directory to others by
  creating the same name folder.
- But actually I want copy these files from my local system (windows XP) to the remote
  system(Linux) located in other country on which I execute my script. But I am getting
  the error as "Destination Path not found" means I am not able to connect to remote
  that's why.
- I use SSH Secure client.
- I use an IP Address and Port number to connect to the remote server.
- Then it asks for user id and password.

  But I am not able to connect to the remote server by my python script.

Can Any one help me out how can I do this??

Comment: you can have a look at this http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576810-copy-files-over-ssh-using-paramiko/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`paramiko`](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/docs/) provides a `SFTPClient` that can be used to do this.

```
import paramiko

source = r'C:\Somedir\somefile.txt'
dest = r'/home/user/file.txt'
hostname = 'linux.server.com'
port = 22 # default port for SSH
username = 'user'
password = 'secret'

try:
    t = paramiko.Transport((hostname, port))
    t.connect(username=username, password=password)
    sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(t)
    sftp.put(source, dest)
finally:
    t.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Sir. But still I am facing a problem.    I am using python 2.7 Version. when I execute my script as per your answer it is showing an error as "No module named paramiko". It is because my python version do not have this module in the library. Can you please tell me How can I add this module in my existing python installation? Please help me out. :)

Comment: Download and install [pycrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) first, then [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/).

Comment: Hi, Thank you.But while installing "pycrypto" I am getting the error as below:                                                 (1)- warning: GMP or MPIR library not found; Not building Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath.                                     (2)- building 'Crypto.Random.OSRNG.winrandom' extension          (3)- error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat ------->>>>>Can you please tell me how can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I used the same script, but my host failed to respond. My host is in different network.

WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. If you're looking for help, consider [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).